# gradle file config to target android API 22

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I have installed Android Studio 3.1.13 with gradle 4.8.1 and java 1.8.0_171, previously installed. I have installed also the SDK API 22 because I need to test an app in Android 5.1.1
The problem is that the default configuration has compileSdkVersion 28 and I had changed it to 22. I have tried many settings but there are always errors due to the version of android API

My current module build.gradle is:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
   compileSdkVersion 22
   buildToolsVersion '22.0.1'
   defaultConfig {
     applicationId "com.company.test"
     minSdkVersion 22
     targetSdkVersion 22
     versionCode 1
     versionName "1.0"
   }
   buildTypes {
      release {
          minifyEnabled false
           proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
      }
   }
   productFlavors {
   }
  }

   dependencies {
      compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
      compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
   }
```

and the proyect build.gradle is

```
buildscript {

  repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
  }
  dependencies {
    //classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
  }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
       google()
       jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

When I tried to build, the IDE now says
The SDK Build Tools revision (22.0.1) is too low for project ':app'. Minimum required is 25.0.0

Don't know how can I build and test and app for API 22. I'm newbie in Android develpoment. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand your question, the app needs to be tested running on android api level 22 right?
Based on this assumption I would say the most straight forward solution would be to keep every value on default (as long as this worked for you before). Just lower the minSdkVersion to 22. 
Short explanation of most important values:

- compileSdkVersion 22 : API Level the app is compiled against
- buildToolsVersion '22.0.1' : Buildtools Version to compile code (has to match compileSdkVersion)
- minSdkVersion 22  : This is the minimum api you want the app running on.
- targetSdkVersion 22 : Simply says, you tested your app running on specified API. Google now uses this to determine if your app is up to date to be published in Playstore or not

As emandt already mentioned BUILDTOOLS and gradle should be up to date, as well as targetSdkVersion and compileVersion.

TESTING APP ON API Level: 
As long as you compiled your app for a target higher than minSdk you can simply build and install the apk to a device running the requested API level.

Comment: thanks Rustyhamsterr and emandt.. now it works with the minSdkVersion 22 and compileSdkVersion 28

Answer (score 0):

The "buildToolsVersion" string should be compatible with the "classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:x:x:x" setting.
You have to lower the second setting until it is accepted.

However I suggest to use latest BUILD TOOLS and latest GRADLE and not revert back to an old ones. Those Tools affect only the Build procedure, not the App itself.